# How to update epoll events after epoll_wait?

Tags: c, events, epoll

I have the following code excerpt (heavily redacted to remove unimportant details) which fails under a rare and particular set of circumstances.

```
struct epoll_event *events = calloc(MAXEVENTS+1, sizeof(struct epoll_event));
struct sockaddr_in in_addr;
socklen_t in_len = sizeof in_addr;

while(1)
  {
  int n = epoll_wait(efd,events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    struct epoll_event *evI = &events[i];
    uint64 u64 = evI->data.u64;
    int type = u64>>32, fd=u64, fdx = fd;

    if(type == -1)
      {
      while((fd = accept4(fdx, &in_addr, &in_len, SOCK_NONBLOCK|SOCK_CLOEXEC))>-1)
        {
        setNew_Connection(efd, fd);
        storeAddrPort(fd, &in_addr, &in_len);
        }
      }
    else
      {
      if(evI->events&(EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP|EPOLLRDHUP)){closeConnection(fd);}
      if(evI->events&EPOLLOUT)  //process out data stuff
      else if(evI->events&EPOLLIN) //process in data stuff and possibly close a different connection.
      }
    }
  }
```

Listening sockets are differentiated by `-1` in the upper part of `evI->data.u64`

`setNew_Connection` does the usual accepting stuff like adding the new socket to epoll etc

`EPOLLET` is used.

Now it all works brilliantly except under the following circumstances it fails because `events` is only updated in the `epoll_wait` so a connection closure does not affect the `n` events until after returning to the top of the `while(1)` loop.

1. `epoll_wait` unblocks with 3 events queued in the events struct table.
2. First event (n=0), is incoming data after which code decides to close a connection (e.g. file descriptor 8) as it is no longer needed.
3. 2nd event (n=1) is an incoming new connection.  `accept4` assigns fd:8 as it has recently become available. `setNew_Connection` adds it to the epoll list.
4. 3rd event is incoming data for the connection closed in step 2. i.e. fd:8 but it is no longer valid as the original fd:8 connection was closed and the current fd:8 is for a different connection.

I hope I have explained the problem adequately.  The issue is that queued events in the `events` table are not updated when a connection is closed until the code returns to `epoll_wait`.  How can I code around this problem?

Comment: you can mark the connection to be closed, and do a closing loop after the events handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orel gave me the answer but I thought I would post the complete code solution.  Instead of

`close(fd)`

I use

```
shutdown(fd,SHUT_RDWR);
FDS[FDSL++] = fd;
```

The `shutdown` prevents anymore data being read or written but doesn't actually close the socket.  `FDS[FDSL++] = fd;` stores the fd so that later after the n events are done, it can be closed with `while(FDSL)close(FDS[--FDSL];`

```
int FDS[MAXEVENTS],FDSL=0;

struct epoll_event *events = calloc(MAXEVENTS+1, sizeof(struct epoll_event));
struct sockaddr_in in_addr;
socklen_t in_len = sizeof in_addr;

while(1)
  {
  int n = epoll_wait(efd,events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    struct epoll_event *evI = &events[i];
    uint64 u64 = evI->data.u64;
    int type = u64>>32, fd=u64, fdx = fd;

    if(type == -1)
      {
      while((fd = accept4(fdx, &in_addr, &in_len, SOCK_NONBLOCK|SOCK_CLOEXEC))>-1)
        {
        setNew_Connection(efd, fd);
        storeAddrPort(fd, &in_addr, &in_len);
        }
      }
    else
      {
      if(evI->events&(EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP|EPOLLRDHUP)){closeConnection(fd);}
      if(evI->events&EPOLLOUT)  //process out data stuff
      else if(evI->events&EPOLLIN) //process in data stuff and possibly close a different connection.
      }
    }

  while(FDSL)close(FDS[--FDSL];
  }
```